# Declare a function parameter with returning value error

Tags: go, generics

I am writing a method to do metrics that can wrap any method. Something like:

```golang
func DoAndMonitor(f func() error, simpleKey string) {
    metrics.IncrCounter("activity."+simpleKey+".cnt", 1)
    if err := f(); err != nil {
        metrics.IncrCounter("activity."+simpleKey+".fail", 1)
    } else {
        metrics.IncrCounter("activity."+simpleKey+".fail", 1)
    }
}
```

This works for some cases. But it is not easy to use, say I have any functions below,

```golang
myMethod() (val1 string , val2 string , err error)
myMethod()2 (val string , err error)
myMethod()3 ( err error)
myMethod()4 (val int64,  err error)
```

When I use `myMethod()`, I may write something like:

```golang
ret1, ret2, err := myMethod()
if err :=nil {
    //log 
    return nil, err;
} else {
    //do something...
    return something,nil
}
```

But when I use `DoAndMonitor`, I hope the `DoAndMonitor` function can return the same type as `myMethod` like :

```golang
ret1, ret2, err := DoAndMonitor(func(){
   return myMethod() 
},"mykey");// this is what i hope, but i can't do this now

if err :=nil {
    //log 
    return nil, err;
} else {
    //do something...
    return something,nil
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why is the error discarded in the first example and returned in the last example?   Explain how you want to the return values to work in more detail.

Comment: @Zombo, sorry for missing the simpleKey. Question has been edited

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get to this is by using type parameters and making a few variations of the same function.

```
func DoAndMonitor(f func() error, simpleKey string) { ... }
func DoAndMonitor1[T any](f func() (T, error), simpleKey string) T {
    x, err := f()
    if err != nil {
        metrics.IncrCounter("activity."+simpleKey+".fail", 1)
    } else {
        metrics.IncrCounter("activity."+simpleKey+".success", 1)
    }
    return x
}
// and so on...
```

You could then invoke your function like so:

```
x := DoAndMonitor1[int](func() (int, error) { return 42, nil }, "foo")
```

A quick playground link to demonstrate this, but with panics instead of your nice metrics. :)
https://go.dev/play/p/SMAhUCoIYcj

Comment: what go version do i have to use ?

Comment: 1.18 or greater. It's the newest current version.